# Can a DSLR be used to host a webinar?

Tags: dslr

Can a DSLR be used to stream a web conference / webinar? In my exact case I have a Canon 70D available.

Is this possible and how would I get started setting it up?

Comment: I heard from a friend who specializes in streaming services tell me that DSLRs usually don't work well. I have no experience nor a source so this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Do you need to be able to live stream, or just record to post somewhere later?

Comment: @RyanWeaver live video

Answer (score 1):

FYI the Canon 70D can't record for more than 29 minutes, 59 seconds at a time. If you're just streaming, look into the [BlackMagic Web Presenter](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/blackmagicwebpresenter). It can trick your computer into thinking that any HDMI or SDI source is a webcam.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a webinar camera needs the following features:

- Recording time: You can set the camera up and it records unattended for the whole length of the webinar (which could be 1 hour or more). This includes a big-enough storage card and a reliable battery pack.
- Flip screen: You can see the framing while you record yourself
- Audio: The camera or an external microphone should record in good quality

It seems that the Canon 70D has all these requirements. But you finally have to try it out yourself.